# Prof that series converges

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence

$(x_n)$, $x_1=\sqrt2$, $x_2=\sqrt{2}^\sqrt{2}$, $x_3=(\sqrt{2}^\sqrt{2})^\sqrt2$

$x_\left(n+1\right) = (\sqrt2)^\left(x_n\right)$

Does this series converge?

Comment: yeah, the convergence of sum of $x_n$

Comment: No, since $x_n>1$, so their limit cannot be zero.

Comment: how should i demonstrate this? i need to demonstrate for class

Comment: Are you talking about a series $\sum_n x_n$ or a limit of a sequence $\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n$?

Comment: (i) Your recursion isn't consistent with your value for $x_3$ (exponentiation isn't associative), and (ii) probably you're asking about a _sequence_, not a _series_...? (Each has a technical meaning, and they're not interchangeable.) Assuming my crystal ball is accurate, you might try to show $(x_n)$ is increasing and bounded above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the steps you need to prove.

- First prove that $1 < x_n < 2$ using induction.
- Nest prove that $x_n$ is a monotone increasing sequence using induction.
- Now recall that due to completeness of the real numbers a [monotone increasing sequence bounded above converges](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_convergence_theorem#Convergence_of_a_monotone_sequence_of_real_numbers). Call the limit as $L$.
- Make use of limit laws/rules to conclude that $L = \sqrt{2}^L$
- Prove that $L = 2$

Comment: a little example? this is a new lesson for me...

Answer (score 0):

Prove that your sequence is increasing, and then prove that $1 < x_0 < 2$ and that if $1 < x_n < 2$, then $1 < x_{n+1} < 2$ as well. This will prove that the sequence is bounded, and since the sequence is increasing, it must converge.

Comment: seems too complicated... don't know how to do it :(